# Netflix hystrix shared request caching

Tags: caching, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix, hystrix

I'm using spring cloud based on Netflix OSS architecture. I need to cache results of one of my methods which is using Get-Set-Get pattern.

```
 public class UserService {    
    @CacheResult
    @HystrixCommand
    public User getUserById(@CacheKey String id) { // GET
        return storage.get(id);
    }

    @CacheRemove(commandKey = "getUserById")
    @HystrixCommand
    public void update(@CacheKey("id") User user) { // SET
        storage.put(user.getId(), user);
    }
}
```

Now my question is pretty simple. I need to know can I have a distributed cache if I've multiple instances of this service running? If yes, can I use something like Redis if the size grows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes man see in [docs](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#request-cache)

How to example of implementation:

```
public class UserService extends HystrixCommand<Boolean> {
     private final User user;

     public User getUserById(String id) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("AnyUser"));
        user = storage.get(id);
        return user;
    }

    public void update(User user) { // SET
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("AnyUser"));
        this.user = user;
        storage.put(user.getId(), user);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean run() {
        return user == null || (user != null && user.id == 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getCacheKey() {            
        return (user != null ) ?String.valueOf(user.id):"";
    }
}
```